How does event loop handles async await internally?
Let us say we have the following async function -
async function foo(x,y) {
  x = x+1
  await fetch('some_url')
  y = y+1
}

When the function foo encounters await, the execution of foo must be suspended and its context must be removed from the call stack. Because only then the event loop will be able to execute other functions by pushing them to call stack. But when the fetch resolves and returns, y = y+1 still has to be executed. How does the event loop handle that?
On searching online, everywhere I find that when await is encountered, the execution of async function is suspended and the event loop can execute other tasks. But how is that possible ? Because if the context of foo is popped off from the stack (to execute other tasks), how does the event loop know that it has to execute y = y+1 after the fetch resolves.
Please provide any documentation that answers the above question.

@Teemu If it is not popped, then how will the event loop push other functions on the call stack so that synchronous code continues executing?

Take a look at the standard, it might shed some light to how await works.

@Teemu It is popped from the stack

Do you understand how generator functions can be suspended (at yield) and later resumed by a .next() call?

The Specification
as you tagged this language-lawyer
Agent & Execution Context
The "event loop" is an unspecified term, the specification describes something called Agents - an agent is something that can run something (and usually there is "just one" which is usually called "the event loop", but there might also be multiple, i.e. Webworkers). An agent also has execution contexts - where each execution context references a function, and holds environment records where i.e. variables "live". Such an execution context "just exists", so it does not have to be currently executing. To track execution, each agent also holds a stack of these execution contexts. Whenever a function is called, a new execution context is created and placed on top of the stack and when a regular function unwinds, the execution context is removed from the stack. The upmost execution context is the one that is currently executed and through which the agent is currently iterating.
Jobs, Job Queues
Now when an asynchronous event occurs, i.e. a timer finishes or fetch has fetched something, then you might want to resume something, but you cannot do it directly as the agent might be currently running some other execution context. Thus instead the asynchronous event will Create a Job, which is an "abstract closure" - so some description of what the agent should do in the future. This job is then placed on one of many job queues. When the agent is done with its current execution - its execution context stack is empty - then it goes over the job queues, picks up one of the jobs and performs the steps described in it, usually the abstract closure will describe how to place an execution context onto the stack and then "jump into it".
Thus if you do something like this:
function a() { ... }
setTimeout(a, 1000)

Then the call to setTimeout(...) will do sometthing to set up a timer, the call returns (the execution context is popped off) and the agent continues with other things. Then later, when the timer finishes, it enqueues a Job, the agent will pick up the Job, and the Job will construct an execution context for the function a and start executing it.
Now we could do something similar also with Promises:
new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
  .then(a)
  .then(b);

This basically does the same thing as above, just that the Job scheduled by the timeout will trigger resolution of the Promise, and that again will then place Jobs for each "promise reaction" in the job queue, in this case closures to call a and b.
await
Now the await keyword doesn't do much special - it just combines all the things described above. Let's look at the specification:

27.7.5.3 Await ( value )
[...]

Let asyncContext be the running execution context.
Let promise be ? PromiseResolve(%Promise%, value).
Let fulfilledClosure be a new Abstract Closure with parameters (v) that captures asyncContext and performs the following steps when called:



Let prevContext be the running execution context.
Suspend prevContext.
Push asyncContext onto the execution context stack; asyncContext is now the running execution context.
Resume the suspended evaluation of asyncContext using NormalCompletion(v) as the result of the operation that suspended it.



Let onFulfilled be CreateBuiltinFunction(fulfilledClosure, 1, "", « »).
[...]
Perform PerformPromiseThen(promise, onFulfilled, onRejected).
Remove asyncContext from the execution context stack and restore the execution context that is at the top of the execution context stack as the running execution context.


So basically, it constructs an abstract closure that when run, takes the current execution context and puts it back on the agent's stack. This abstract closure is then attached as a promise reaction to the promise the right hand side expression of await evaluated to, then it will pop of the current execution context ("stop execution of the async function"). When the Promise is settled, the promise reactions are placed as Jobs on a Job queue, the agent will pick it up, place the execution context of the async function on the execution context stack, and resume execution.

How to map the Specification to the CPU?
as you tagged this v8
Now if you want to put the specification into code and build a JavaScript engine - you would use different threads for different agents, a Job queue would really just be a queue where some kind of function pointers are stored. Now environment records are a bit more tricky - naively one could use some kind of Map<string, JSValue> to store variables but that would be super slow. On the other side, not every variable can be placed on the stack (of a JIT compiled function), i.e. due to closures or async/generator functions. Thus instead the engine will likely put some kind of "stack frame" onto "the heap", so write variable values into some area outside "the stack", where it can be kept even if execution of a function is halted. Stopping and resuming a function (an async or generator function) is also a bit more tricky - an interpreter or virtual machine could just halt at an arbitrary instruction, and remember the instruction it was at and store it somewhere to resume later. For JIT compiled functions this gets more interesting, as one cannot jump back into bytecode at arbitrary places and quite some machinery is needed.

Not sure why you want to exclude the event-loop so bad. Sure ES specs are written so that this concept is not needed, but it would help explaining all that "magics" in your answer. Moreover when you use examples that aren't ES either (setTimeout, fetch)

@Kaiido because "one event loop" promotes the misguided idea that "JavaScript is single threaded" - With Webworkers and SABs this isn't true anymore for a long time. And I really like the description of agents in the spec and want to promote that people "read the source" :)

Why would an event loop promote the idea of a single thread? The event loop manages the parrallelism of the operations, that's thanks to the event loop that JS (and not ES), can have non blocking features, like setTimeout and fetch, i.e. all that you have to call "magic" because the restrained model you frame your answer into doesn't handle that. I'd even argue that on the contrary, dismissing the evnt-loop promotes the misguided idea that JS engines work on their own, and that UAs are written in JS somehow.

Now you are mixing concurrency and parallelism. My "restrained model" is what is called JavaScript (as specified as ES262) and implemented by V8 and SpiderMonkey (among others).

I'm talking about this definition of parallelism I'm not mixing anything. And I made it clear in my comments that I separated what's colloquially called JS from ES. JS comprises the common web standards on top of ECMAScript, which is the only thing that ES-262 does define. V8 or SpiderMonkey don't have a setTimeout nor a fetch implementations, these are not ES, but they are "JS".

When an await is encountered in code (either in an async function or in a module), the awaited expression is executed, while all code that depends on the expression's value is paused and pushed into the [microtask queue][1]. The main thread is then freed for the next task in the event loop. This happens even if the awaited value is an already-resolved promise or not a promise.
Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await
